# dataLabels overlap bar line chart HighCharts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, highcharts

Only the biggest number on bar char overlap the bar line

[image]

I tried to add `maxPadding` for the xAxis, but it looks like too bad for small numbers.

Another way i tried
`crop: false, allowOverlap: true, overflow: 'allow',`

but there anothers problems with text cut appears

Answer (score 0):

You can set the higher axis `max` property or try to adjust the axis `left` and `width` properties. Take a look at the example in the following demo:

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jvo1sth2/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.max
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.left
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.width

Comment: In this case, it doesn't work correctly too. If we pass for the label for example:
3_875_234 then this number will inside the bar line, but must be before the line

Comment: This is the standard behavior of `dataLabels` when there is not enough space for them - e.g. when your chart has a fixed width or is getting shrunk.  If you want to force `dataLabels`  to be always before the column, then `crop: false, overflow: 'allow'`  settings are the best ones, but in that case, they will overlap the axis in case not enough space.  What are your expectations of the behavior of `dataLabels`, when there is no space? The alternative way would be to fully hide `dataLabels` or rotate them. You can also just set the `min-width` for your chat. Let me know!

Comment: The expectation is all time to see dataLabels. Even is a very small space. dataLabel  always will have 8px